# How to utilize OpenCL 1.1 on Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, opencl

OpenCL 1.0 came with nVidia driver for Mac OS X 10.6.  I wonder if/how it is possible to update header files to utilize OpenCL 1.1 API.  Greatly appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not that easy, you need also a OpenCL 1.1 implementation + the CL 1.1 headers. Until OS X isn't updated to support OpenCL 1.1, you simply can't use it.